# twilio sms webhook api

Tags: python, rest, twilio, twilio-api

I'm would like to programmatically change the webhook for a given number (and possibly enumerate available numbers) or messaging service, but I can't find the API documentation. From [Our Request to your Webhook URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request):

> You can configure the URLs and HTTP Methods Twilio uses to make its requests via your account portal in the Twilio Console or using the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is the [incoming-phone-number resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource).

In Python, you can use the following script to update its `sms_url` prop:

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

incoming_phone_number = client \
    .incoming_phone_numbers('PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
    .update(sms_url='https://www.your-new-sms-url.com/example')

print(incoming_phone_number.friendly_name)
```